# ant-builder task not finishing

Tags: ant, build, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using worklight 6.2.0.00.20140613-0730 and ant-worklight-builder.jar to build a app.
Most of my build script works except when I try to build my app.

It does something, it generates a native folder for a app and a .wlapp, but only for one environment.
On the ant log I have no error, nor a finished message.

Parts of my build are

```
<target name="Build App" depends="Stage App">
    <app-builder
        worklightserverhost="http://server-address:1234"
        applicationFolder="${stage.apps.dir}/xpto"
        nativeProjectPrefix="xpto"
        outputFolder="${build.apps.dir}/xpto"/>
    <!--  environments="list-of-environments" -->
</target>

<target name="Stage App" depends="stage.prepare">
    <antcall target="regeneratenative.iPad" />
    <antcall target="regeneratenative.iPhone" />
    <copy toDir="${stage.apps.dir}/xpto" overwrite="true" filtering="true">
        <fileset dir="${apps.dir}/xpto" />
    </copy>
    <copy toDir="${stage.apps.dir}/xpto2" overwrite="true" filtering="true">
        <fileset dir="${apps.dir}/xpto2" />
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="regeneratenative.iPad">
    <delete failonerror="true" dir="${apps.dir}/xpto/ipad/native/"/> 
</target>   

<target name="regeneratenative.iPhone">
    <delete failonerror="true" dir="${apps.dir}/xpto/iphone/native/"/> 
</target>
```

I would expect it to generate the entire environment or at least show me a error.
Does anyone have any idea on what might be happening?

Comment: Not much to work with here; need to be able to reproduce in order to debug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a environment setup problem as the above code run just fine on a windows box.
On my mac sometimes it hangs up some other times it runs just fine.